# python P8000 unable to connect: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: python, postgresql, pg8000

I am using pg8000==1.30.5 in python 3.12

I was migrating from psycopg2

But connection I got an error:

```
pg8000.Connection(self.db_username, database=self.schema_name, host=self.db_host,
                               password=self.db_password,
                               port=self.db_port)
```

the error is the follow:

```
pg8000.exceptions.DatabaseError: {'S': 'FATAL', 'V': 'FATAL', 'C': '28000', 'M': 'no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx", user "xx", database "xx", no encryption', 'F': 'auth.c', 'L': '543', 'R': 'ClientAuthentication'}
```

You might think is postgres server problem, firewall, my vpn/ip, access control, permissions etc...

However I was working with "psycopg2" without any problem:

```
psycopg2.connect(database=self.schema_name, host=self.db_host, user=self.db_username,
                               password=self.db_password,
                               port=self.db_port)
```

I can not understand why one works and the other does not.

Comment: What does the relevant `pg_hba.conf` entry look like?  Have you checked the server logs to see if there is a more detailed error message logged?

Comment: I have no access to that file. anyway psycopg2 seems to work why should I to change server configuration to make work another client library ?

Comment: Presumably psycopg2 and pg8000 are connecting in different ways. Knowing the connection rule or the error message in the logs (or both ideally) would help us determine the what the difference is.

Comment: psycopg2 is willing to connect over ssl by default, while pg8000 is not.

Answer (score 0):

As of pg8000 1.31.0, by default an [SSL connection will be attempted](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#connect-to-postgresql-over-ssl) using lenient settings, so it should work in the same way as psycopg.